# AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'Window'

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I am trying to get up and running with PySimpleGUI. I tried running the following code (from https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-quick-tour):

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
event, values = sg.Window('Get filename example', [[sg.Text('Filename')], [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()], [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()] ]).Read()
```

This is on a Windows 7 box, with Python 3.7.1, and PySimpleGUI version 4.18.0.

BTW, those two lines should work from a python command line, I think. But, even if I save them as a file (with no other python lines, just newlines and comments), I get

```
(Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blorfmorlfle\bin\MoveStagedFiles.py", line 15, in <module>
    event, values = sg.Window('Get filename example', [[sg.Text('Filename')], [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()], [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()] ]).Read()
AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'Window'
```

Searching stack overflow for similar errors, all the results threads were different.

FWIW, I have uninstalled and reinstalled PySimpleGUI.

FWIW2, the following works fine.

```
sg.Popup('Hello From PySimpleGUI!', 'This is the shortest GUI program ever!')
```

Any thoughts? I have heard some python releases are problematic for PySimpleGUI because of tkinter issues. Is there a recommended release?

Comment: Looks local environmental to me. 3.6 and 3.8 worked fine using the 2 lines provided. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46163555/78712831-4514f000-78e7-11ea-809a-34277c840128.jpg https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46163555/78713053-9d4bf200-78e7-11ea-8fdf-4782a2b2f131.png

Comment: Hmm. I just tried this on another 3.7.1 installation on a Windows 10 machine and it worked fine. Not sure what the difference would be. Perhaps %PATH is munged on my Win7 box somehow. But, still, if PySimpleGUI imports at all, how could it be missing attributes?

Comment: Uninstalling and then reinstalling PySimpleGUI27 fixed this error for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first installed PySimpleGUI a couple years ago, just to play with it. Having heard that it was just one python file, I just dropped it in a folder I was using for testing code.

That older version of PySimpleGUI isn't fully functional now, as it's missing things like `Window`, `theme`, etc. I installed the latest using pip. But, I have still been running test code from the same folder. So, when I imported PySimpleGUI, the old version was ahead of the newer PySimpleGUI's install path. Basically, I was importing an older version that I didn't remember was installed in the current working directory. Since the old version didn't have a version variable, it took a while to realize that I wasn't importing the version that `pip show PySimpleGUI` was reporting as installed from the OS command line. Embarrassing. But, lesson learned.

Thank you to everyone who responded in this thread. Eventually, @acw1668's suggestion made me realize what was going on.

Comment: In the PySimpleGUI Issue template on GitHub it's recommended you add 2 lines to your programs when you're debugging them.
print(sg)
print(sg.version)
It's a common problem when working with packages to get them from the wrong location.  The first print, printing the import name, tells you the path to the file that was imported. It's good for any package of course so try it next time you're struggling with weird package results like these. It's a lot quicker than looking through your environment variables for the path order.

Comment: @MikeyB, that's very handy!

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with python 3.6.8 and PySimpleGUI 4.18.0 with the same two lines of code that you provided and it did not work for me, too (Kernel died).

However, running the other example from the quick tour (https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-quick-tour), which simply provides the code in a more readable way, worked for me:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')  # please make your creations colorful

layout = [  [sg.Text('Filename')],
            [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()], 
            [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel()]] 

window = sg.Window('Get filename example', layout)

event, values = window.Read()
window.close()
```

I hope that this might help

Comment: That is easier-to-read code. But, I get an error `AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'theme'` when I run it. I am wondering how PySimpleGUI imports at all if not all of its attributes are loading.

Comment: Sounds like an installation issue to me. Have you looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240983/pysimplegui-error-code-attributeerror-module-pysimplegui-has-no-attribute-po ?

Comment: I have the same impression that it's an installation issue. I have read that thread (it's the top search result!). As I said on the OP, I uninstalled and re-installed PySimpleGUI. My script was not named PySimpleGUI.py. And, the pop-up window example works for me. Not sure why the other PySimpleGUI module attributes are causing errors. I am wondering if my python 7.1 install is the issue somehow, though I still don't see how I could import the module (which, at least at one time, was one large file) and not get the attributes.

Comment: Which tkinter version do you have? 8.6?

Comment: Yes, tkinter v. 8.6.

Comment: BTW, I checked `dir(PySimpleGUI)` and 'Window' is _not_ it in for the problem install. It _is_ for the ones that work. The recommendation to uninstall and re-install seems obvious. But, I have done that, per the thread @Daniel05 linked and I am still getting this. What should I uninstall and re-install (or how do I do those things more thoroughly) if not PySimpleGUI?

Comment: From inside python, is there a way to tell which version of PySimpleGUI I have imported? I am not seeing a version variable that I can check. The comment above where 'Window' isnt't in the module's namespace makes me wonder if I am not somehow importing an older version, maybe from my python 2.7 install or something. (BTW, I still need 2.7 for a few things. Uninstalling it would be a last resort.) FWIW, my top three PATH strings are 3.7 related, i.e. ending in ..\Python37\, ..\Python37\scripts, ..\Python37\Lib\site-packages

Comment: Try adding `print(sg.version, sg.__file__)` after importing `PySimpleGUI`.  What are the output?

Comment: That did it. Or at least led me to it. Thanks!!